# How to keep a programming course interesting?

Tags: language-agnostic

I guess, the following is a standard problem on every school or university:

It is Your job to teach programming. Unfortunately, some of the students
are semi-professionals and have years of experience while others do not even know the basic concepts, e.g. the concept "typed variable".

As far as I know, this leads to one of the following situations:

1. Programming is tought from its very basics. The experienced students get bored and discontinue to visit the lectures. As a consequence, they will miss even the stuff they do not already know.
2. Teachers and professors claim that they require basic knowledge (whatever that means). Inexperienced students cannot follow the lectures and a lot of them will focus on unimportant stuff (e.g. understanding every detail of a complex example while not getting the concept behind the example). Some of them will give up.
3. Universities invent an artificial programming language to give experienced programmers and newbies "equal chances". Most students will get frustrated about the "useless language".

Is there a fourth solution, which is better than those above?

Comment: Interesting this year I had to teach programming and I thought my school was the only one where newbie and semi-professional were in the same class, it was very difficult for me. What a relief to know I'm not alone ! ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the best way to keep it interesting is to bring up practical and interesting exercises along the theory. Taking a problem-solution approach is great (with interesting, funny, exciting, real-world problems). This requires the professor himself to have hands-on experience, work with new technologies and know them pretty well and not just teach what he had learned a couple decades ago.

The thing is, programming should be learned by practice. The instructor should focus on motivating students to code and try to solve problems themselves. This can be done by assigning a complete life-like project at the beginning of the course and working through the subproblems that occur in the project in the class. This way, students will have an idea why some specific feature in the programming language exists and where it might be useful.

Just a thought though. Not tried it! ;)

Comment: Absolutely.  Nothing motivates like having someone write small programs they can relate to.

Answer (score 13):

IMO this is a problem based on the placement of the students, not something you should be too interested in dealing with on your end as a teacher.

If the course is an introduction to programming a computer, then you really need to start with the basics.  If you have a classroom full of professionals who know how to program and they don't show, it was either a problem with your course description, or the school forcing them to take the class as a pre-req without allowing them to test out.

Your job should be to describe what you want to teach in the course description, and teach it.  If students enroll who are overqualified, that's their problem.  I think the only thing you really need to avoid is trying to make the course too advanced for beginners if your course really is for beginners.

Comment: You are right. Unfortunately, in many universities, students are required to take courses in "programming for beginners".

Comment: Many schools now have separate introductory programming courses before the introductory CS course that involves programming and the higher-level courses. Students can get waivers from the super-intro courses.

Comment: Your answer would be perfect in a perfect world. Sadly, this is far from the reality. And no matter how wrong it is, it is a problem that needs solving. What I'm trying to say is, this is not an answer for the posed question, it is an answer to the question on what different tracks there should be

Comment: The question has no real answer if you're put in a situation where you can't win.  The point is that if you try too hard to answer the question (make your beginning course very interesting for advanced students), you will make the course less effective for the people it's  supposed to serve.

Answer (score 3):

I recently attended a course in which there was a very wide spectrum of experience in programming among the students. They still managed to keep the experienced programmers in the class interested by having an exercise program in which they timed the practical parts of the exercises (the programming part), and posted the results in a high score chart. At the end of each lecture, the professor gave some pointers as to how we could improve our times even more. As we all know, all engineers love competing for topping such lists, so we kept showing up, and even learned a new thing or two. 
The inexperienced students managed to complete the exercises too, even if they didn't care too much about their times.

Don't know if your course is one that can implement this solution, but if it is, you should really consider it.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are a couple if things you can do to help bridge the gap between advanced and beginner students and to keep everyone interested and involved in the course.

### Advanced Workshops

If it can be arranged (using PHD students etc.) run an optional weekly workshop which anyone can attend, but which is aimed at the more experianced students. Set a code task / challange each week and then at the workshop go through various solutions to the problem and discuss the implications and the theory behind the different choices.

This provides an interesting challange for the more experianced coders as they have something to get thier teeth into. It opens some debate and can help intermediate people grasp interesting concetps and if you get people to present thier solutions, it introduces an open reviewing style which is beneficial. It also helps the beginners in that you don't have to present them with really advanced concepts in the main lecture series just to keep the experienced people interested.

### Student Involvement

Experienced people generally are experienced because they enjoy coding etc. and a lot of people love to share their knowledge. A really good way to use this, and to help both beginners and advanced students is to get the more advanced students involved in the teaching. If you run classes/labs where students complete exercises, try getting volunteers from the more experienced students to act as mentors/ supervisors for the labs. When the beginners struggle they can help out by explaining fine details or subtleties etc.

This can really help the beginners, as there are never usually enough staff available for everyone to be able to ask individual questions. It can also really benefit the more advanced people, as having to explain concept which you "know" is a great way to reinforce them in your own mind, and even to discover that you have subtle misunderstandings in your own knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Don't assume more than you need to; try to select programming environments which don't have too much intellectual baggage. You may think a C "Hello world" program is simple, but that requires understanding source files, compilation, static typing and block structuring. There are not easy concepts for a beginner. In comparison, typing "print 'hello world'" into a Python shell avoids them.  Declarations, compound types, object orientation, pointers, floating point, recursion, modularity, threads, callbacks, modularity, networking, databases and so on are all major concepts which require effort to learn. And, there are plenty of fun things to be done without them. Your goal should be to get everyone in the group doing programming exercises as soon as possible.

Mixed ability teaching is hard; stream it by splitting the group up if you can. Maybe publish a quiz of basic concepts, and have an optional basic concepts section for those who didn't get 100%. Some people think they are experienced programmers but have misunderstood basic ideas.

If the course time available is too short to let people try lots of exercises, then I'd drop the more advanced material before I dropped practical work.

Answer (score 0):

In one course I took, a large part of the course grade was derived from a end-of-term project which was announced in advance with extra credit available for assorted add-ons and frills. Sufficiently experienced student could start working on it while their less prepraed brethren were being taught the basics.

But as Dave Markle says, part of this is a matter of getting the right students into your class: you really want a cohort that is fiarly well matched at the start.

Answer (score 0):

If you have many experienced students or this is an upperclassmen/graduate level-course, you should focus on integration into existing ecosystem. Being able to understand and integrate into an existing project rather than to always work from scratch is the most important skills you can give to give to those students.

Thus, programming assignments should come from real world scenarios. E.g., assign them tasks in an open source project. This can also make it more interesting, especially as their work may become part of a real world project.

If it's really beginners, tough luck, you will have to stick to the basics though if the students are non-CS majors, you can create problems from their own domains (e.g., engineering, chemistry, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I think your could be toast.

After some point, the difference is just to wide. It will take the whole year to get the beginners to the point that they can even understand stuff that wont bore the more advanced people.

However this clearly depends on the topic and setting. For some combinations of those the solution is teach to the level that the class is billed for. Those that are to advance will get board and quit, those that are to inexperienced with fall behind and quit. Don't worry about it to much as neither should have taken the class anyway. If on the other hand they need to take the class then some one further up the ladder  messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Sitting in your chair watching someone talk is boring (even if you talk well).

Things are interesting if you can achieve something, when you can manipulate the world and have a moment of success. So add as many practical exercises as you can and make really sure that they can do them in time and that they can do them successfully in time.

Nothing is more frustrating than to hear: "Well, I'm sorry that you couldn't complete it. You can find a solution here. Let's copy that and pretend it did work and move on." Examples during a course are simple and the people in front of you know that. So if they can't even solve the simple examples you bring along for them, what are they going to think?

Answer (score 0):

I always think it is best to learn through practice. At the beginning of the course especially it is incredibly boring to teach language syntax in a lecture. It is far better to require your students to complete some work on their own or in a lab with assistants. This allows the more experienced students to get through the work quickly.

Once this is done you can have a lecture where you discuss some of the solutions to problems. Why they are good and why they are bad.

This works especially well if you also structure your course in such a way that students are always building on their rpevious work. The first week can be something simple like calculate how many days old I am from my birthday. A problem that is relatively simple mathematically but has a few weird cases. This might take several hours for someone inexperienced. Especially if they are learning syntax at the same time. But it gives them a simple goal to work toward.

After this you can expend on it. eg: take lasts weeks program and add functionality that allows it to batch process a file. This teaches people the importance of restructuring and refactoring, and can be expanded week after week. You may even want to distribute a good piece of work from the previous week for those that are falling behind to use. Obviously you will need to make sure people don't get too far behind, but this is a nice way to make sure that everyone feels that they have a fair shot at it even if their previous week's work wasn't too good. Those who are doing well will end

The key is to keep your lecture sessions relatively high level, and have people learn the syntax on their own, or with lab assistants. You can teach them different ways of thinking about a problem but the actual act of writing code is much easier to learn by doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I once through a scheduling nightmare ended up teaching a beginner class and an advanced class in the same classroom at the same time. What I did was divide my time between the two levels by starting out giving the advanced group an assignment to do in class while I worked with the beginners and then giving the beginners an assignment while I worked with the advanced. You could do something similar (only having the groups self-select into the group they wanted to be in). Prepare some extra material for the more advanced ones and you are off to the races.

Another strategy is to keep everything at the beginner level, but offer the more advanced students some other material to do for extra credit (or even as substitution for some of the simpler tasks you require of the beginners).  Discuss the more advanced assignments with them outside of class or individually while the class is working on practical work in the lab.

Keeping the lectures interesting with plenty of real world examples is helpful too. I tended to lecture as little as possible though and present the material more through class discussion and practical exercises and through asking leading questions. Making them find the information to answer your questions (and class participation was part of the grade) will make them pay more attention.

I also ended each semester with a course project that I only described what they had to do  in order to get a B. An A would involve doing work beyond that including work in an area not covered in class. The more advanced students can then really shine by looking for really cool new things to do and even the beginners usually find a way to do something not covered by the course. It's amazing how much extra effort they will go to when they don't know how much more they have to do to get an A. Other instructors would be amazed at the quality of the end of the course projects I got and several of them started using the same method.

Answer (score 0):

It may be better to break up a few areas of concern with what some would call, "Introductory Programming":

1) Introduction to personal computers and modern computing.  Assuming that the course's software runs on windows, there may be some that need to cover the basics of a computer, e.g. what is a hard drive, keyboard, mouse, monitor, CPU, motherboard, etc.  Note that this has nothing to do with even one line of code other than naming operating systems potentially.  For some people this may be new to them and thus having a course that covers the basics, may well be worth it.  Also in this course would be ways to use a mouse and all its various buttons, what are the various kinds of cables and connections people have, what are drivers, what are patches, what are parts of a network, e.g. firewall, router, load balancers, etc.  The idea here isn't to get into how to configure a firewall perfectly, but rather that the person understands what various hardware components are for and possibly how to configure a home wireless network as the most complicated concepts taught.

2) Principles of programming.  This would start with the idea of what are the steps are there to execute a sequence of commands.  Things like printing and performing Mathematical operations, e.g. converting from Imperial to metric,would be covered with possibly sorting being the most complicated example, viewed from a variety of different algorithms and an understanding at a basic level of big-O notation.

3) Introduction to Data Structures and Advanced Programming.  Now, let's introduce the concept of a relational database and how databases work in general and have projects with real world application, e.g. have each student take a list of something they have like DVDs or CDs and put these into a database schema to efficiently store all this data.  Also, the idea of floating point arithmetic and its limitations, e.g. that a computer doesn't store the whole value of pi but rather an approximation that should be good enough in most cases.

4) Introduction to Parallel Programming and Operating Systems.  Here you would have some in depth work in building an Operating System and handling how to write code that can run concurrently or in Parallel and how efficient are various programs under different circumstances.

That is how I could see someone breaking up programming so that it isn't where someone can learn in a week enough to pass the final without looking at anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I have frequently been in this situation, first on the student side of things, and then on the teaching side.

Most schools force those sort of courses and their curriculum. This is silly, but such is life. If your school does allow it, I would suggest offering students attendance waiver if they pass an early screening test. It is in your interest and the interest of the freshmen to not sit in a class where a significant portion of the population is bored. Even being in a room with tons of people starting at their laptops harms discourse.  Everyone is required to attend tests and submit assignments, but they at least don't have to show up.

Once you work with the novices, figure out if they're majors or nonmajors. Nonmajors will resent being in a CS course, you have to try and make it approachable for them. E.g., use examples from physics or chemistry or math rather than from building an interactive gui system.

If they're CS majors, they'd better damned be interested :)

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is that teaching sample programs is dead-boring for most people. Searching, sorting, classification of 7-bit ascii input, using unix & make, opening a file, writing a file...

These are *boring* problems. Regardless of their importance/usefulness, these are tools. Unfortunately, tools are what's taught in intro courses, not problems.

But you need tools to be able to solve a problem. So it's a kind of chicken-egg problem.

Answer (score 0):

Real world examples of code the student can imagine themselves doing out of their free time.
I remember a teacher telling me to use const values it was the tax of something. I only had to use the value in two places. She asked what if i need to change it i said its only in two places and i'll change it by hand also i couldnt imagine the gov ever changing the tax %.

I cant think of an non complex example where i would use a const so i wouldnt try teaching them to use that but for arrays i would simply write a guessing game then when the player wins the game, it plays back all the guesses in the same order to them. There is no easy way to do that w/o arrays and i could see how keeping track of someones steps/guesses would be useful (bragging rights to how quickly a person guessed it).

Answer (score 0):

On the first day give the syllabus (what they will learn) and required basic knowlege (things you must know or else not take this class) and stick with it. After these all you can do is teach well (explain things well, answer questions, give a joke or two now and then etc). Caring who attends class, whether or not the field is boring, whether student lied about pre-requisites or not, who listens and the other yada yada is beyond your controls. Besides, you should expect adults to be adults. If students skip class and ace test, maybe that is best for them. If they skip class and bomb tests, well maybe they are in the wrong place.

I hated when professors had this mentality when I was in college. Now as a working professional I understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Center the programming exercises around either sports or movies.